# Get list of column value which does not contain a specific keyname in another column of same table sql

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table which has a column name lets say  message Id and the message Id may have lot of keyname and value stored in separate column .

| MessageID | Keyname | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | ab | 1 |
| Second | ab | 1 |
| Third | ac | 2 |
| First | kk | 4 |

So I need to get the message Id which has "ab" keyname but not "kk". The answer am expecting is Second as it dont have "kk"  Keyname.

How could we achieve it ?

Comment: not sure i understand the question, if you are filtering out 'ab' and 'kk' aren't you looking for Third?

Comment: select the messageId that have keyname = 'ab' and in the resulting message Id look for messageId which dont contain keyname = 'kk'

Comment: "*Filter out 'ab' keyname*" means not expecting it in the result set, probably you meant "filter in" according to your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to gather MessageIDs that satisfy your conditions:

```
SELECT MessageID
FROM tab
GROUP BY MessageID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyname = 'ab' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Keyname = 'kk' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Else 0 is required here

Comment: You're right. Probably with count, the else clause can be avoided altogether.

Comment: Using count is also incorrect have a look on comments in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351125/filtering-by-count-and-specific-value-from-a-related-table/76352267#76352267

Comment: That's a different issue. That happens when you don't use the `CASE` expression inside the count. He's also telling you to use the CASE expression explicitly: `"*and non-compliant DBMS usually require COUNT(CASE WHEN locale='en' THEN 1 END)*", in DBMSs different that MySQL, like Snowflake.

Comment: To deepen it, the `CASE` expression is generating a field that has either 1 or NULL (thanks to the missing `ELSE` clause), which allows the `COUNT` to operate correctly. When you don't use that `CASE` expression, MySQL will return either 1 or 0, and `COUNT` will always count you all non-null values, hence every value returned by `field='value'`.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can us join condition in where clause

```
SELECT MessageID
FROM tab
WHERE keyname = 'ab' or  keyname != 'kk'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a subquery

```
select * from (select * from test where keyname = 'ab')
as tab where keyname != 'kk';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5qqDzVM2) here

Comment: No this dint work reason it the first subquery return all the rows matching to keyname= 'ab' but when you apply keyname != 'kk' , it just gives the same rows first and second again. Where as my expection is only to get the value as "Second"

Comment: in your data First and Second are duplicate entries, why do you expect one over another?

Comment: The message Id can have multiple keyname and values.  SO in my case MessageID first has keyname "ab" and "kk" where as my message id second has only "ab". I need to get the message Id which has "ab" keyname but not "kk"

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way to do it using the conditional aggregation by function `sum()` :

```
SELECT MessageID
FROM mytable
GROUP BY MessageID
Having
sum(case when Keyname = 'ab' then 1 else 0 end)> 0 and
sum(case when Keyname = 'kk' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```